# How to manage memberships of clubs/teams (groups) and handle permissions in Django?

Tags: django, django-models

I'm creating a Django project to help people run clubs and community groups. I'm new to Django and I can think of lots of different ways to add users to clubs and manage permissions, but it's not clear what the right way to do it is.

I have a "Club" model and a "Team" model. A club can have many teams, and members of a club may or may not be members of a team, but a user must be a member of the club in order to join the team. There will also be various permissions around what a club/team member can and cannot do (and what a club/team administrator can do)

My current plan for managing membership is to create "ClubMembership" and "TeamMembership" models and create the relationships using ManyToManyField.through, as demonstrated here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ManyToManyField.through

For permissions, it looks like I should use django-guardian and set permissions when people join/leave a club/team. Would it make sense to also have a "members" foreign key to django.contrib.auth.models.Group in my club/team models to keep track of this?

It feels like I'm doubling up in some areas by having membership managed by membership models and then also using groups to set permissions. Is there a better way to approach this, or anything I should modify/consider?

```py
class Team(models.Model):

    # Fields
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    # Relationship Fields
    club = models.ForeignKey(
        'organizations.Club',
        on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="teams", 
    )
    members = models.ManyToManyField(
        'organizations.Users.user',
        related_name="teams", through='TeamMembership', through_fields=('team', 'user')
    )
    administrators = models.OneToOneField(
        Group,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="teams", 
    )

class TeamMembership(models.Model):

    # Fields
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    # Relationship Fields
    team = models.ForeignKey(
        'organizations.Team',
        on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="teammemberships", 
    )
    user = models.ForeignKey(
        'users.User',
        on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="teammemberships", 
    )
```

To summarize my questions:

1. Is the "TeamMembership" model the right way to associate users with
   Teams?
2. Should I include Groups in my models to house users for
   permissions purposes, or will this cause problems?
3. Is there another approach I should consider?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to StackOverflow.

1) Team Membership looks like a good way to do it.  I'm not sure what the `name` field would be used for but it looks like it may be redundant (from Team name or user name).

2) It would not be a bad idea to implement Groups for permissions.  That way the security part of your app is not dependent on the functional part, and vice versa.

3) The best way to implement `django-guardians` permissions with Groups would be to use `signals` that are sent whenever a `Team` or `TeamMembership` instance is created or destroyed.  The creation/deletion of a `Team` would result in the creation/deletion of a corresponding permissions group, and the creation/deletion of a `TeamMembership` would result in the addition/removal of that person in the `Team` permissions group.

Comment: Thanks so much for your answer! I think the "name" field was something I forgot to remove from a previous iteration. I prototyped a bunch of different things and ended up more or less where I started.

Using Signals is a good idea, I've dabbled with them a little, so hopefully I can figure it out.

Thanks again!